# Magento API Manage Indexes

Tags: magento, xml-rpc

I use Magento 1.9 with API 1.0 XML-RPC to add and modify products. It works pretty well, but I need to re-index manually in Magento Backend after each modifiation to make changes visible on my shop.

All the indexes are set to "Update on Save" - how can I trigger re-index after API modifications?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The indexes should be being triggered after each API update request if you have them all set to update on save. Could it be a cache issue rather than index. Where are you experiencing the problem, products not showing up in categories, or attributes not showing correctly on frontend?

Comment: I'm experiencing the error that products are not showing up in categories / front page as well as is the product not available trough the direct link.